# AnimationDrawable.setBackgroundResource takes a lot of time

Tags: android

I have one issue in my app , setBackgroundResource takes a lot of process time .Is there any way to run this method in another thread ,I have tried to use AsyncTask , but it doesn't have access to UI thread .  Is there any way to perform another task while this method is processing  ?
Thx in advance.

Comment: "setBackgroundResource takes a lot of process time" -- how have you determined this (e.g., via Traceview)? What are you using for the background resource that is taking so long?

Comment: i bet he is using hundreds pngs in AnimationDrawable

Comment: Yesk i have a lot of png images , is there any way to perform this task in another thread

Answer (score 0):

You could load the drawable in an AsyncTask, then modify the UI from complete:

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Drawable>() {
    protected Drawable doInBackground(Void... ignored) { 
        return context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.giant); 
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Drawable d) { 
        myView.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
    }
}
```